# JS datePicker is readonly ONLY on my computer but no others

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datepicker, readonly

I have a brand new Lenovo Yoga 920 fresh out of the box with Chrome (64.0.3282.140) and Firefox (58.0.2) installed with no extensions.

As part of my daily routine I use an online accounting app (KashFlow) and the invoices use a js-datepicker to choose a date from.  The datepicker usually can either be typed into or a date can be clicked from the popup calendar.

When I use my new Yoga with KashFlow all of the datePickers are greyed out and set to readonly (as in, they can be clicked but can't be typed into).  Here is a snippet of code;

```
<input class="js-datePicker widest hasDatepicker needsclick" name="date1" id="date1" size="12" value="01/01/2018" readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

You can see the 'readonly' part at the end.  To clarify, the datePicker is still usable by clicking a date but it can't be typed in.

This **ONLY** happens on my Yoga.  Every other computer I use (I have access to five other computers) work perfectly by allowing typing as well as clicking.  Literally every other computer works great except the Yoga and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I have ensured that Java and Flash are always allowed for the site. (If I disable Java for the site the datePickers become active again but the entire site becomes unusable).

The only browser on my Yoga that allows typing in the datepickers is Edge.  Both Chrome and FireFox show the datePickers in a readonly, greyed-out state.

I have checked the Chrome settings for my Yoga and another computer side-by-side and both the JavaScript (V8 6.4.388.41) and Flash (28.0.0.161) versions are identical.

Why on earth would a Lenovo Yoga 920 operate any differently?  Is there some setting within Windows that's wrong?  I am stuck and looking for some inspiration here.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: My guess is a browser extension.

Comment: Readonly is the only correct behaviour here, every browser that work different might have a problem. As always with HTML/JS, the complete page and scripts are required to check the problem properly. And yes, extensions can be one thing :)

Comment: @Barmar Hello.  I sync my Chrome across all computers so any extensions are identical across them all.

Comment: Do you see `readonly` if you do `View Source`?

Comment: What if you clear cookies for that site?

Comment: @Barmar Yes.  Viewing the source on the Yoga shows 'readonly'.  The same source on my other computers don't show it.  I have also cleared cookies/cache/everything and still the same behaviour.

Comment: Does KashFlow have tech support? It's their application, I don't see how we can help you. This is a site for helping programmers fix their code, not helping you use someone else's application.